# Pods sharekit with xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, sharekit, xcode6.1

I have used the pod sharekit with my app and it was working fine, until I updated the XCode to 6.1 I started get errors a lot of errors and I have tried to solve them one by one. Now my problem

When I try to run the app under the simulator I get the following message:

```
Unable to run app in Simulator : An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)
```

And when I try to Archive the app to send it to App store I get this:

```
Symbols tool failed
```

> Archive validation failed due to the listed below:

```
Unable to validate your application.
The archive is invalid /var/folder/fv/........ .ipa does not exist.
```

Also when I try to deploy the app direct to the device I get the following message:

> ```
> >     App installation failed
> >     Could not inspect the application package.
> ```

I stuck in this problem from 15 days ago I tried to get the solution by searching on google in the forums.

Note: I tried to remove the "pods" from the project and comment all the sharing code the app worked fine, I mean the problem is from pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be issue with GooglePlus;
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/an-important-announcement-for-ios.html

I guess ShareKit is not updated with the latest GooglePlus SDK, so

```
Replaced pod "ShareKit" with 
pod "ShareKit/Twitter"
pod "ShareKit/Facebook"
pod "ShareKit/Pocket"
pod "ShareKit/Evernote"
```

you should add googlePlus SDK separately if required;

Ref: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/961

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is issue with Google plus SDK being used via pods, need to integrate google plus sdk separately

Replace pod "ShareKit" with followings

pod 'ShareKit/Twitter'
pod 'ShareKit/Facebook'
pod 'ShareKit/Pocket'
pod 'ShareKit/Evernote'

for Google plus 
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You are right guys thank you.
The issue is with Google plus.
Because I'm using the sharing feature with Facebook and Twitter only I just update my pod file to be:

```
pod "ShareKit/Facebook"
pod "ShareKit/Twitter"
```